# Mismatched input 'x' expecting {<EOF>, ';'} when using GROUPING SETS

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, grouping

I am using Spark SQL to create `grouping sets` with total columns to reduce the size of a file which I have previously cubed.

My code is as follows

```py
final_sum = sqlContext.sql('''
  SELECT case when GROUPING(x_flag)=1 then 'total' else x_flag END AS x_flag,
  ...
  from trans,
  group by x_flag,...,
  GROUPING SETS(
    (x_flag,y_name)
    ...
  )
''')
```

My column `x_flag` is indexed 0,1 (as integers) and I am trying to get `grouping sets` based on that column mainly.

I currently get the following:

> mismatched input *x_flag* expecting {, ';'}(line 14, pos 11)

Is there a method to fix this without having to reflag the column as *y* and *n* or is there some error which I am missing with using integer in `case when`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce the error, but I have created a working example for you.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, 0),
     (0, 1),
     (1, 0),
     (1, 1)],
    ['x_flag', 'y_name'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("trans")

spark.sql("""
    SELECT
        CASE when GROUPING(x_flag)=1 then 'total' else x_flag END AS x_flag,
        CASE when GROUPING(y_name)=1 then 'total' else y_name END AS y_name,
        count(*)
    FROM trans
    GROUP BY
        GROUPING SETS(
            (x_flag, y_name),
            (x_flag),
            (y_name)
        )
""").show()
# +------+------+--------+
# |x_flag|y_name|count(1)|
# +------+------+--------+
# |     0|     0|       1|
# |     0| total|       2|
# | total|     0|       2|
# | total|     1|       2|
# |     0|     1|       1|
# |     1| total|       2|
# |     1|     0|       1|
# |     1|     1|       1|
# +------+------+--------+
```

Make sure you use correct syntax: in your question, I have noticed a comma after the `from` clause.
Also, `group by` doesn't seem to require additional arguments when using `grouping sets`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, there were a few commas I missed off!! (Doh) That has been fixed!